# SD begin affecting OLED display

Tags: esp8266, i2c, spi, sd-card, display

Okay, I'm using `u8g2` library for my OLED display. After calling SD.begin(4) function, I cannot display anything on my OLED.

I'm using `U8G2_SH1106_128X64_NONAME_F_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, /* reset=*/ U8X8_PIN_NONE);` constructor from `u8g2` library since I'm using `I²C` for the display and SPI for microSD reader. I removed the `CS Pin 4` from `SD.begin()` and I can now display something on the OLED.

How did supplying CS Pin parameter to `SD.begin()` function affected the `I²C` OLED display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pins 4 and 5 are the I2C pins that belong to the built in I2C peripheral on the Arduino. You have to put your CS line for the SPI SD card on a different pin.

**EDIT:**
The answer above is relevant to the Arduino ATMega328-based board, not ESP8266-based NodeMCU board. This answer is not relevant to ESP8266 or NodeMCU with regard to hardware I2C, as the ESP8266 does not have a dedicated hardware I2C peripheral.

Comment: I'm using ESP8266 (NodeMCU v3) and pin numbers for I2C is D1 & D2 (printed on the board). Man, this caused confusion to me. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The [NodeMCU docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/sdcard/) say to use Pin 8 for SPI (SD Card) slave-select.